# The light stays on after removing a ceiling fan that had 2 sets of wires

Tags: wiring

I removed a ceiling fan/light to put in a new fixture without a fan.  The box had two cables and each set had a black wire a white wire and a bare wire. I did not keep track of how the wires were ordered.  I thought that I could cap one set of wires from one cable and use the other cable for my new light fixture. Wrong.  The new fixture is up but the light is on but will not turn off at the switch.  The old fan setup had a light that turned on off at the switch and a remote that controlled both the light and the fan. It also had a pull string to turn the fan on and off.  How can I rewire it so the light turns on and off at the switch?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: One of the black wires is probably unswitched power that allows the remote and pull chain to function, the other black wire is probably switched.  If you have a multimeter, you could test, if not, swap the black wire from the fixture to the other black wire, cap the one you disconnected and see what happens.

Comment: Ok.  Thank you I'll try  that.

Comment: Thanks again George.  This worked!!!